# XMPP client can not receive offline message

Tags: ejabberd

**client can not receive the offline message,the ejabberd server throw an exception.the log message is:**

```
[error] <0.677.0>@ejabberd_hooks:run_fold1:368 {function_clause,[{xmpp_codec,get_ns,[{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:client">>},{<<"to">>,<<"bingo@im.com">>},{<<"from">>,<<"bingo4@im.com/2685976459613694105436">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"delay">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:delay">>},{<<"from">>,<<"im.com">>},{<<"stamp">>,<<"2017-01-18T18:28:45.851121Z">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"Offline Storage">>}]},{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"2222222222">>}]}]}],[{file,"src/xmpp_codec.erl"},{line,6151}]},{xmpp,get_subtag,2,[{file,"src/xmpp.erl"},{line,405}]},{mod_offline,find_x_expire,2,[{file,"src/mod_offline.erl"},{line,537}]},{mod_offline,'-pop_offline_messages/3-fun-1-',2,[{file,"src/mod_offline.erl"},{line,586}]},{lists,'-filter/2-lc$^0/1-0-',2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1286}]},{mod_offline,pop_offline_messages,3,[{file,"src/mod_offline.erl"},{line,582}]},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,382}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,365}]}]}
running hook: {resend_offline_messages_hook,[<<"bingo">>,<<"im.com">>]}
```

**my configure:**

```
max_user_offline_messages:
    - 5000: poweruser
    - 2000: admin
    - 100


mod_offline:
    db_type: sql
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
    store_empty_body: true
```

**configure mistake or bug? ejabberd version 16.12**

Answer (score 0):

This is a ejabberd's bug fixed recently and will be included in 17.01